# Why does ''grep [Ff]irst *.txt'' not match a file containing "First"?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, glob, quotes

Example from Mendel Cooper's "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide"...

```
$bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$mkdir Quoting_Experimenting
$cd Quoting_Experimenting
$echo This is the first line of file1.txt > file1.txt
$echo This is the First line of file2.txt > file2.txt
$grep [fF]irst *.txt
file1.txt:This is the first line of file1.txt
file2.txt:This is the First line of file2.txt
$touch first
$grep [fF]irst *.txt
file1.txt:This is the first line of file1.txt
```

Why does grep not find file2.txt after first has been created?

Comment: What do you think `grep [fF]irst *.txt` means?

Comment: This is [3.5.8 Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), and you're discovered why it's important to use quotes in shell commands.

Comment: @jhnc I think `grep [fF]irst *.txt` means "find the word first or First in any text file in the current directory".

Comment: Except that isn't what it means. The shell sees a `[` so it attempts [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) before `grep` ever runs.

Comment: @jhnc Thank you. Your question and answer helped me to understand the answer of anubhava and comment of glennjackman. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: That `tr` question may be a related one but not the exact dupe of this `grep` problem.

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote the search pattern in grep command otherwise shell expands **unquoted pattern** `[fF]irst` to `first` only (due to filename `first` being present in your current directory):

So use:

```
grep '[fF]irst' *.txt
```

[- Official BASH documentation on filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)

As per this doc (emphasis is mine):

> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set (see The Set Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters `‘*’`, `‘?’`, and `‘[’`. If one of these characters appears, and is **not quoted**, then the word is regarded as a **pattern**, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of **filenames matching** the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking for a match with any case, instead of using a regex, just use the ignore case command:

```
grep -i first *.txt
```

Comment: However, that would also match `firST`.

Comment: By the way, I made the purpose of my answer clearer to avoid this kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Warlei, you'll find most downvotes do not come with any explanation. I understand as a new-ish user that it's frustrating. Try not to take it personally.

Comment: Actually, I am not a new member, but an old absent member. But, thanks anyway, for your kind advice.